# Are legal questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Example: [Legal issues when using first aid techniques that require certification in foreign countries](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/158/43)

> I am a certified first responder in France, but laws and protocol may differ from a country to another.
>
> May I use the techniques I am certified for here in other countries without legal issues? I'm not so much speaking about civil issues, but penal, as I could be considered non-certified outside my country.

Comment: I'm the OP of this question. I see the point, and I didn't think about that actually, I was focusing on the first-aid matter. Now I have no opinion on whether this question belongs to here or not.

I see several options:
1) Maybe I should simply remove it (I won't contribute to "legal" but for this question, so no need to open an account there) - 2) Or leave it as it is as the beta is the proper moment to handle such cases ? - 3)
Or reword it ? Something like "First Aid guidelines are based on international standards. Does it make me certified in foreign countries?". Let me know, I'll follow.

Comment: @Shlublu No idea, I don't have any opinion either :)

Answer (score 12):

I don't think that legal issues would fall under health, even if they are about medical laws. I think we should focus on questions that are physical medical problems. There is a [Law Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) on Area 51, so if that ever goes into beta these questions would fit better their.

Answer (score 5):

I would say they are off topic just because there is so many issues dealing with legal advice in a single country and when you have a site that has a worldwide audience it can quickly lead to issues.